# What perl code samples can lead to undefined behaviour?

Tags: perl

These are the ones I'm aware of:

1. The behaviour of a "`my`" statement modified with a statement modifier conditional or loop construct (e.g. "`my $x if ...`").
2. Modifying a variable twice in the same statement, like `$i = $i++;`
3. `sort()` in scalar context
4. `truncate()`, when LENGTH is greater than the length of the file
5. Using 32-bit integers, "`1 << 32`" is undefined.  Shifting by a negative number of bits is also undefined.
6. Non-scalar assignment to "state" variables, e.g. `state @a = (1..3)`.

Comment: Check this page: http://blog.plover.com/prog/perl/undefined.html

Comment: This should be community wiki

Comment: I'm fascinated to know why someone thinks this question should be closed.

Comment: It's not really an answerable question, as it is asking about unsupported and undefined behaviour in the Perl specification, as well as any bugs that may be lurking.

Comment: @Ether: I think that's the point. If you know what doesn't work, especially if there's a good reason for it, you can avoid that.

Comment: @Ether: I interpreted the question to be asking for minimal code samples/patterns of code that cause undefined behaviour in the core of Perl, not in arbitrary modules off CPAN.  I think these can be listed pretty objectively, as the OP's partial list shows.

Comment: The "static variable hack" is already in my list (as number 1). Other examples are not really undefined behaviour, imho. And relevant docs just say "don't do that"

Answer (score 5):

One that is easy to trip over is prematurely breaking out of a loop while iterating through a hash with `each`.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my %name_to_num = ( one => 1, two => 2, three => 3 );

find_name(2);    # works the first time
find_name(2);    # but fails this time

exit;

sub find_name {
    my($target) = @_;

    while( my($name, $num) = each %name_to_num ) {
        if($num == $target) {
            print "The number $target is called '$name'\n";
            return;
        }
    }
    print "Unable to find a name for $target\n";
}
```

Output:

```
The number 2 is called 'two'
Unable to find a name for 2
```

This is obviously a silly example, but the point still stands - when iterating through a hash with `each` you should either never `last` or `return` out of the loop; or you should reset the iterator (with `keys %hash`) before each search.

Answer (score 4):

These are just variations on the theme of modifying a structure that is being iterated over:

`map`, `grep` and `sort` where the code reference modifies the list of items to sort.

Another issue with `sort` arises  where the code reference is not idempotent (in the comp sci sense)--`sort_func($a, $b)` must always return the same value for any given `$a` and `$b`.

Comment: I can't remember the circumstances any more but at one time I tried to abuse `sort` by passing it a non-idempotent sortsub with amusingly bizarre results.