# Why does Perl print a value I don't expect after incrementing?

Tags: perl

I'm running this one-liner from the command line:

```
perl -MList::Util=sum -E 'my $x = 0; say sum(++$x, ++$x)'
```

Why does it say `"4"` instead of `"3"`?

Comment: See also [What perl code samples can lead to undefined behaviour?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2176453/what-perl-code-samples-can-lead-to-undefined-behaviour)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are modifying `$x` twice in the same statement. According to the [docs](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Auto-increment-and-Auto-decrement), Perl will not guarantee what the result of this statements is. So it may quite be `"2"` or `"0"`.

Comment: The passage in the docs is not relevant. It says the result isn't defined because operand evaluation order of operators isn't defined. While that's true for `+` (used in the example), it's not for the comma operator (used by the OP). The LHS of the comma operator *is* documented to be evaluated before the RHS.

Comment: Mind you, Perl doesn't guarantee the result in this case either, but it's for a different reason. Knowing the result depends on knowing whether pre-increment returns the original (now modified) scalar, or a copy of it, and *that* is not documented. (It's the former, fyi.)

Answer (score 7):

First, keep in mind that Perl passes by reference. That means

```
sum(++$x, ++$x)
```

is basically the same as

```
do {
   local @_;
   alias $_[0] = ++$x;
   alias $_[1] = ++$x;
   &sum;
}
```

Pre-increment returns the variable itself as opposed to a copy of it*, so that means both `$_[0]` and `$_[1]` are aliased to `$x`. Therefore, `sum` sees the current value of `$x` (`2`) for both arguments.

**Rule of thumb: Don't modify and read a value in the same statement.**

* — This isn't documented, but you're asking why Perl is behaving the way it does.

Comment: +1 I think you meant to type " the current value of $x `(2)`".

Answer (score 3):

Because both incrementers are executed before the sum is calculated.

After both execute, `x = 2`.

```
2 + 2 = 4.
```

Comment: If that was the reason, then `sum(++$x, ++$x)` and `sum(0 + ++$x, 0 + ++$x)` would give the same result.

Comment: @ikegami not true, because the expression `++$x` has an lvalue nature but the expression `0 + ++$x` has an rvalue nature. Usually that's irrelevant since they're being used as rvalues, but in the undefined case where you do two preincrements inside a function call, it happens to have an early-vs-late-bind-ish effect.

Comment: @hobbs, You say what I said isn't true, yet you proceed to agree with my point that the lvalue nature of the op is the actual reason. This is covered in detail in my answer.