# Is the use of an uninitialized variable undefined behavior?

Tags: perl, undefined-behavior

I don't know if "undefined behavior" means something in Perl but I would like to know if using not initialized variables in Perl may provoke unwanted behaviors.

Let's consider the following script:

```
use strict;
use warnings FATAL => 'all';

use P4;

my $P4;

sub get {
    return $P4 if $P4;

    # ...connection to Perforce server and initialization of $P4 with a P4 object...
    return $P4;
}   

sub disconnect {
    $P4 = $P4->Disconnect() if $P4;
}   

sub getFixes {
    my $change = shift;

    my $p4 = get();
    return $p4->Run( "fixes", "-c", $change );
}
```

Here, the variable `$P4`, which is meant to store a P4 object after a connection to a Perforce server, is not initialized at the beginning of the script. However, whatever the function which is called first (`get`, `disconnect` or `getFixes`), the variable will be initialized before being used.

Is there any risk to do that? Should I explicitly initialized the `$P4` variable at the beginning of the script?

Comment: Note that `$P4->Disconnect()` is not documented to return undef

Comment: @ikegami If so, what is the meaning of `-> undef` in the documentation? https://www.perforce.com/perforce/r15.1/manuals/p4script/perl.p4.html#perl.p4.disconnect

Comment: Ah, I was going by the version of the docs on metacpan.org, which is an older version that has actually been removed from CPAN.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just a couple of straight-up answers to basic questions asked.

> if "undefined behavior" means something in Perl

Yes, there is such a notion in Perl, and documentation warns of it (way less frequently than in `C`). See some examples in footnote <sup>†</sup>.  On the other hand, at many places in documentation one finds a discussion ending with

> ... So don't do that.

It often comes up for things that would confuse the interpreter and could result in strange and possibly unpredictable behavior. These are sometimes typical "undefined behavior" even as they are not directly called as such.

The main question is of how uninitialized variables relate, per the title and

> if using not initialized variables in Perl may provoke unwanted behaviors

This does not generally result in "undefined behavior" but it may of course lead to trouble and one mostly gets a warning for it. Unless the variable is legitimately getting initialized in such "use" of course. For example,

```
my $x; 
my $z = $x + 3;
```

will draw a warning for the use of `$x` but not for `$z` (if `warnings` are on!). Note that this still succeeds as `$x` gets initialized to `0`. (But in what is shown in the question the code will abort at that point, due to the `FATAL`.)

The code shown in the question seems fine in this sense, since as you say

> the variable will be initialized before being used

Testing for truth against an uninitialized variable is fine since once it is declared it is equipped with the value `undef`, admissible (and false) in such tests.

See the first few paragraphs in [Declarations in perlsyn](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlsyn#Declarations) for a summary of sorts on when one does or doesn't need a variable to be `defined`.

---

<sup>†</sup> A list of some behaviors specifically labeled as "undefined" in docs

- Calling [sort](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/sort) in scalar context

  > In list context, this sorts the LIST and returns the sorted list value. In scalar context, the behaviour of sort is undefined.
- Length too great in [truncate](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/truncate)

  > The behavior is undefined if LENGTH is greater than the length of the file.
- Using flags for [sysopen](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/sysopen) which are incompatible (nonsensical)

  > The behavior of `O_TRUNC` with `O_RDONLY` is undefined.
- Sending signals to a process-list with [kill](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/kill), where one can use negative signal or process number to send to a process group

  > If both the SIGNAL and the PROCESS are negative, the results are undefined. A warning may be produced in a future version.
- From [Auto-increment and Auto-decrement (perlop)](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlop#Auto-increment-and-Auto-decrement)

  > ... modifying a variable twice in the same statement will lead to undefined behavior.
- Iterating with [each](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/each), tricky as it may be anyway, isn't well behaved if hash is inserted into

  > If you add or delete a hash's elements while iterating over it, the effect on the iterator is unspecified; for example, entries may be skipped or duplicated--so don't do that. It is always safe to delete the item most recently returned by `each`, ...

  This draws a runtime warning (F), [described in perldiag](https://perldoc.perl.org/perldiag#Use-of-each()-on-hash-after-insertion-without-resetting-hash-iterator-results-in-undefined-behavior)

  > Use of `each()` on hash after insertion without resetting hash iterator results in undefined behavior.
- [Statement modifier (perlsyn)](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlsyn#Statement-Modifiers) used on `my`

  > The behaviour of a `my`, `state`, or `our` modified with a statement modifier conditional or loop construct (for example, `my $x if ...`) is undefined.

Some of these seem a little underwhelming (predictable), given what UB can mean.  Thanks to ikegami for comments.  A part of this list is found in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2176453/4653379).

Pried from docs current at the time of this posting (v5.32.1)

Comment: Re "*way less frequently than in C*", And the reason is two-fold: 1) There's only one implementation of Perl, so it's natural to think that Perl is what `perl` does, and 2) `perl` doesn't run on the diverse architectures that C has had to run on. The only officially undefined behaviour that comes to mind is using a lexical variable without first executing its `my`.

Comment: @ikegami OK, that's a nice explanation for it. Perl's (docs) could have more as well, for a lot of those "so don't do that," if they cared for it.  As for such official designations in Perl, the SO question at the link in the answer lists a few  that are indeed called that in docs (`sort` and `truncate` and a few other practices), and _'each' after insertion_ is flagged as such in `perldiag`.  But then there can't possibly be much more while the C standard has hundreds I think (as you say, C's so varied in many ways)

Comment: Added a list of what I can confirm is specified as "undefined behavior" in docs

Comment: Despite the docs, the behaviour of modifying a var twice in a statement is predictable. Complicated, but predictable. It's more unspecified than undefined. Still, it would be an ugly ugly thing to do. /// `sort`'s return value is definitely more along the lines of unspecified than undefined. /// Finally, I find the restriction of `truncate` really weird. It should be a thin wrapper around the system call, and the system call says: "*If the file previously was shorter, it is extended, and the extended part reads as null bytes ('\0').*" Sounds like an error. Or maybe they meant "not portable".

Comment: By unspecified, I mean subject to change. It's not ever going to, but they reserve the right to do so. (Ran into character limit.)

Comment: @ikegami Agree with all this. I was underwhelmed by it -- disappointed, even! There are far more true UB-like, outright bizarre possible behaviors in Perl (documented).  Perhaps there's more, and better ones?  Didn't think much about `truncate` but I see it now; also, `man 3 truncate` doesn't offer any other reason for being cautious with a Perl wrapper (and it behaves just as you/it says, just checked).

Comment: @ikegami And `each`, which can definitely do funny things, isn't called in the docs. But it prints it as a warning (F) at runtime; it's only in `perldiag`

Comment: @ikegami Found and added two more (`sysopen` with nonsensiical flags and `kill` when both signal and proc are negative). Searched `perldoc perlfunc` for word `undefined` -- so that's most of it I guess.

Comment: hmm? The docs for `each` covers all the weirdness I can think of: Unpredicable order (except for the very narrow circumstance where it is predictable); can't insert (but can delete); iterator is shared by keys, values and each.

Comment: @ikegami That, yes -- but no statement of undefined behavior (spelled with `u` -- British -- in docs though!) from `perldiag`  ...  well, that's what it is --- it does talk about weirdness and it is clear that there may be strange things but it just doesn't bother to call it UB.  That's probably the case at other places in docs as well.

Comment: Well, it uses "unspecified" instead of "undefined", which are interchangeable terms. "*If you add or delete a hash's elements while iterating over it, the effect on the iterator is unspecified*" (with an exception that it's safe to delete the current element). Even in the C standard, "undefined" has its normal English meaning; it's not defined by the standard.

Comment: @ikegami Ah, yes, you're right!  I'll add that...  (it does end with "don't do that" :)

Answer (score 2):

A variable declared with `my` is initialized with `undef`. There is no undefined behaviour here.

This is documented in [`perldoc persub`](https://perldoc.pl/perlsub#Private-Variables-via-my()):

> If no initializer is given for a particular variable, it is created with the undefined value.

However, the curious construct `my $x if $condition` does have undefined behaviour. Never do that.

Comment: As for arrays and hashes, they are created empty.

Answer (score 2):

`my` initializes scalars to `undef`, and arrays and hashes to empty.

Your code is fine, though I would take a different approach to destruction.

---

**Option 1: Provide destructor through wrapping**

```perl
use Object::Destroyer qw( );
use P4                qw( );

my $P4;

sub get {
   return $P4 ||= do {
      my $p4 = P4->new();
      $p4->SetClient(...);
      $p4->SetPort(...);
      $p4->SetPassword(...);
      $p4->Connect()
         or die("Failed to connect to Perforce Server" );

      Object::Destroyer->new($p4, 'Disconnect')
   };
}

# No disconnect sub
```

---

**Option 2: Provide destructor through monkey-patching**

```perl
use P4 qw( );

BEGIN {
   my $old_DESTROY = P4->can('DESTROY');
   my $new_DESTROY = sub {
      my $self = shift;
      $self->Disconnect();
      $old_DESTROY->($self) if $old_DESTROY;
   };

   no warnings qw( redefined );
   *P4::DESTROY = $new_DESTROY;
}

my $P4;

sub get {
   return $P4 ||= do {
      my $p4 = P4->new();
      $p4->SetClient(...);
      $p4->SetPort(...);
      $p4->SetPassword(...);
      $p4->Connect()
         or die("Failed to connect to Perforce Server" );

      $p4
   };
}   

# No disconnect sub
```